# how to write xdr packed data in binary files

Tags: python-3.x, xdr

I want to convert an array into `xdr` format and save it in binary format. Here's my code:

```
# myData is Pandas data frame, whose 3rd col is int (but it could anything else)

import xdrlib

p=xdrlib.Packer()
p.pack_list(myData[2],p.pack_int)

newFile=open("C:\\Temp\\test.bin","wb")
# not sure what to put
# p.get_buffer() returns a string as per document, but how can I provide xdr object?
newFile.write(???) 
newFile.close()
```

How can I provide the XDR-"packed" data to `newFile.write` function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XDR is a pretty raw data format. Its specification ([RFC 1832](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1832.html)) doesn't specify any file headers, or anything else, beyond the encoding of various data types.

The binary string you get from `p.get_buffer()` *is* the XDR encoding of the data you've fed to `p`. There is no other kind of XDR object.

I suspect that what you want is simply `newFile.write(p.get_buffer())`.

Unrelated to the XDR question, I'd suggest using a `with` statement to take care of closing the file.